# Is there value in abstracting NHibernate criterion?

Tags: nhibernate

I'm fairly new to NHibernate, and most of the examples I've seen add some layer of abstraction over the base `Criterion` or `DetachedCriterion` classes. In simple cases, it's some sort of `Query` classes that might look something like this:

```
public class Query<T>
{
    public List<QueryCondition> Conditions { get; set;}
}

public class QueryCondition
{
    public string Property { get; set; }
    public ComparisonEnum Comparison { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

Somewhere in a services or repository layer that query abstraction is translated to a proper `Criterion` object which is then used by NHibernate to retrieve the records.

That example is a gross oversimplification, of course. In my project, I had gone down the road of creating a `Query<T>` class that would contain `AND` and `OR` conditions, and the interface defines a method to translate my custom conditions (which are in some cases much more complicated than the simplistic `QueryCondition` example above) into an `AbstractCriterion` to add to a `DetachedCriterion` built in the service. Part of the reason I did this is that I persist queries associated so users can define a list and save it, but the biggest reason is that it seems to be the prevailing method for the n-tier NHibernate projects I've seen.

However, I'm starting to wonder if the overhead of this abstraction is worth it. It doesn't save me dependencies on NHibernate. Because I'm using futures to batch queries, my projects all have to reference NHibernate to at least access `IFutureValue` for record counts. On top of that, my `Query<T>` class is inextricably tied to NHibernate since it builds the `AbstractCriterion` (though I could easily pull that out to a separate class).

Regardless, the more I look at it, I could simply replace my `Query<T>` with a `DetachedCriteria`. Both are serializable, so I can persist them, and since I wouldn't be building criterion conditions separate from the criterion itself I think I'm less likely to run into alias issues for complex queries. And as far as abstractions go, this one doesn't seem to provide much insulation from complexity.

Can anyone give me reasons why I should abstract NHibernate criteria *other than* the "you might change your ORM one day" (something I'm comfortable saying is an impossibility at this stage in the project)?

Answer (score 0):

It has an advantage in terms of unit testing. `Criteria` API is really great at building queries, but is a real pain for mocking. If you have such class you easily verify condition:

```
 query.Conditions.Contains(requiredCondition);
```

While in Criteria you would need some mocks and verify behavior of application, not output which is much harder.

Only because of this reason I'm still using `Repository` pattern in my apps instead of just using `ISession` directly

Comment: I'm not yet unit testing (I can hear the gasps from the SO community now), but your point makes sense. It also highlights a problem - my service layer, which primarily is a security service that filters data based on the user's security rights, is what translates the `Query<T>` to a `Criterion`. That means unit testing those service methods (which largely parallel repository methods) would be difficult, too.

Comment: instead of `query.Conditions.Contains(requiredCondition);` why not populate an inmemory database with data for each edge case and run the queries on that. No additional layer for translating needed and it has the added benefit of actually testing the real query instead of conditions which you think will lead to the correct results.