# How can I solve this NHibernate Querying in an n-tier architecture?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, onion-architecture

I've hit a wall with trying to decouple NHibernate from my services layer. My architecture looks like this:

> web -> services -> repositories -> nhibernate -> db

I want to be able to spawn nhibernate queries from my services layer and possibly my web layer without those layers knowing what orm they are dealing with. Currently, I have a find method on all of my repositories that takes in `IList<object[]> criteria`. This allows me to pass in a list of criteria such as `new object() {"Username", usernameVariable};` from anywhere in my architecture. NHibernate takes this in and creates a new Criteria object and adds in the passed in criteria. This works fine for basic searches from my service layer, but I would like to have the ability to pass in a query object that my repository translates into an NHibernate Criteria.

Really, I would love to implement something like what is described in this question: [Is there value in abstracting nhibernate criterion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812441/is-there-value-in-abstracting-nhibernate-criterion). I'm just not finding any good resources on how to implement something like this. Is the method described in that question a good approach? If so, could anyone provide some pointers on how to implement such a solution?

Comment: Why are you trying to abstract and hide NHibernate? You should read http://ayende.com/blog/4567/the-false-myth-of-encapsulating-data-access-in-the-dal and http://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton then re-consider your design

Comment: i would add http://ayende.com/blog/4784/architecting-in-the-pit-of-doom-the-evils-of-the-repository-abstraction-layer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

abstracting away the ORM will:

- bring a lot of work of redefining it's API
- make it impossible to optimise/batch database access
- make it a lot harder to understand what queries are executed
- will lead to tons of SELECT N+1

and all for very little value: the vague option to exchange the ORM framework which will most probably have a lot of other problems

- missing features
- subtle difference in implementation
- learning curve

Update: experience

I was once involved in implementing a new provider of an existing DAL abstraction. It ended up performing badly, introduced a lot of bugs, Errorhandling was a mess and sometimes used stale data because the application assumed the default implementation. Reasons:

- Caching does not know context
- Cacheimlementation had different semantics
- batching APIs too different to be abstracted
- Errors are specific to implementation (e.g. *FileNotFound -> FilesearchDialog* is uselesss for a tcp/ip based databases)
- Error recovery is different (each implementation has it's own set of errors it can recover from)
- locking mechanism was different
- no consistent change event in SQL-Databases
- nested transactions
- default implementation bleeded in Model classes
- reimplementing all abstracted Queryies was a lot of work and introduced a lot of copy paste bugs
- querying without explicitly stating the order will return different ordered results in different implementations

It took a lot of refactoring of the application:

- strip out features only one implementation provides
- Cachemanagement for each implementation
- problem of Identity of Wrappers because of transient data
- implement Queries over two datastores very hard

Additional points:

- Migration of Data through the abstract DAL is slow as hell
- implementing yet another implementation will never occur because of the above stated problems it is too expensive (In the mentioned scenario we began to slowly reimplement the whole project)
- it was extreme difficult to implement the correct semantics of the DAL API because there is no context of use in the pure API

Porting (of business tasks) would have been a lot less painfull IMO as we did that for a few because of performance.

Update2: experience2: RoadBlocks while trying to port from NHibernate to EntityFramework (impl with NH but couldn't with EF 4 in reasonable time)

- nested Transactions
- Enum support
- references with compositeId (how to get rid of referenceIds)
- references in Components
- read batching (Futures) which is handy for page + count in one go
- mapping CultureInfo (IUserType support)

Comment: To make this answer complete you really should provide some `cons` to NOT abstracting the ORM away, like PITA testing

Comment: there is no big difference between `testlist.ForEach(e => session.Save(e));session.Flush();session.Clear();` and `var mock = new Moq<SomeRepository>().Call(s => s.GetSomeThing(...)).Returns(testlist).Object;`

Comment: Does the first one hit the database? Not trying to be a PITA myself but curious how you deal with this...

Comment: No PITA here, I'm glad to learn from others. I'm using `SqliteConfiguration.Standard.InMemory()` and each test gets its own session. So this hits the database but since all tests have their own inmemory one, i don't have a problem with speed and isolation. QueryOnly tests could share the same session. Default/test data could be injected by a method you'll write once or for each test individual data.

Comment: Thanks, I have seen this approach but can never seem to export the schema correctly on test setup and end up having to hand massage the generated sql.

Comment: This is the first thing i do when mapping a legecy database: make sure schemaexport will generate the correct schema (use IAuxiliaryObject if needed). Benefits: **1)** i can go back in time, generate the old schema with default data and be up and running **2)** unit testing is easier **3)** Switching the database is much less work **4)** no scripts must be kept up to date for installing

Comment: Thanks for your concise point of view do you have any links for `IAuxiliaryObject`? What actually is this?

Comment: see http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-database-object or the simple in code equivalent `new SimpleAuxiliaryDatabaseObject("Create ...", "DROP ...", /*supportedDialects*/ new HashedSet<string> { typeof(...Dialect).FullName });`

Comment: The SqlLite solution still requires that you setup a lot of data not germane to your test in order to satisfy FK's. Since ISession.Query<T> is implemented as an extension method and is therefore unstubbable, I prefer to use a Generic Repository implementation coupled with a LINQ-aware Specification Pattern. (I wrote a specification library here: [link](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Isg.Specification/). In the case where I need the advanced functionality of an ORM, I'll settle for integration tests. Generic Repository + Specification handles 95% of my production and testing needs though.

Comment: setting up complex data for tests is a simple import of a test or production database. Transactions handle isolation. Wrapping linq (which is specification already) into a specification is often additional work for little benefit. I never felt the urge to stub `session.Query<T>` because i **want** the query to be executed on the system i plan to work with (NH)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the responses! I understand what you are saying, but these answers do not solve my problem. Because of the state of the system I'm writing, I am unable to change my architecture. Instead, I am just going to keep all of my sql/hql/criteria api queries inside of the repository layer instead of trying to expose some sort of a complex query class to my services. This approach should work just fine. For my next architectural approach though, I will consider the points made in the other answers.