# NSubstitute throws CouldNotSetReturnDueToTypeMismatchException when mocking Query on NHibernate Session

Tags: nhibernate, extension-methods, iqueryable, nsubstitute

I have a repository offering a GetAll method which again calls the Query extension method on the ISession instance of NHibernate.

```
public ICollection<Product> GetAll()
{
    return _session.Query<Product>().ToList();
}
```

My unit test looks like this:

```
[Test]
public void GetAllReturnsCollectionFromSession()
{
    IQueryable<Product> productList = new ProductListBuilder().Build().AsQueryable();

    _fixture.Session.Query<Product>().Returns(productList);

    var sut = _fixture.CreateSut();

    var result = sut.GetAll();

    Assert.AreSame(productList, result);

    _fixture.Session.Received().Query<Product>();
}
```

In the _fixture.Session.Query().Returns(productList) statement, NSubstitute throws the following exception:

```
NSubstitute.Exceptions.CouldNotSetReturnDueToTypeMismatchException : Can not return value of type IQueryable`1Proxy for ISession.GetSessionImplementation (expected type ISessionImplementor).

Make sure you called Returns() after calling your substitute (for example: mySub.SomeMethod().Returns(value)),
and that you are not configuring other substitutes within Returns() (for example, avoid this: mySub.SomeMethod().Returns(ConfigOtherSub())).

If you substituted for a class rather than an interface, check that the call to your substitute was on a virtual/abstract member.
Return values cannot be configured for non-virtual/non-abstract members.

Correct use:
    mySub.SomeMethod().Returns(returnValue);

Potentially problematic use:
    mySub.SomeMethod().Returns(ConfigOtherSub());
Instead try:
    var returnValue = ConfigOtherSub();
    mySub.SomeMethod().Returns(returnValue);

   at NSubstitute.Core.ConfigureCall.CheckResultIsCompatibleWithCall(IReturn valueToReturn, ICallSpecification spec)
   at NSubstitute.Core.ConfigureCall.SetResultForLastCall(IReturn valueToReturn, MatchArgs matchArgs)
   at NSubstitute.Core.CallRouter.LastCallShouldReturn(IReturn returnValue, MatchArgs matchArgs)
   at NSubstitute.Core.SubstitutionContext.LastCallShouldReturn(IReturn value, MatchArgs matchArgs)
   at NSubstitute.SubstituteExtensions.Returns[T](MatchArgs matchArgs, T returnThis, T[] returnThese)
   at NSubstitute.SubstituteExtensions.ReturnsForAnyArgs[T](T value, T returnThis, T[] returnThese)
   at Statoil.Wellcom.DataLayer.Implementation.Oracle.UnitTests.Repositories.DwapplicationRepositoryTests.GetAllReturnsCollectionFromSession() in C:\git\WELLCOM\source\Statoil.Wellcom.DataLayer.Implementation.Oracle.UnitTests\Repositories\DwapplicationRepositoryTests.cs:line 123
```

It looks like NSubstitute is unable to set the return value due to Query being an extension method. How would I go about mocking the extension method call on the ISession?

Comment: the answer you probably do not want to hear: ditch the repositories and use an inmemory database for tests. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12913174/671619

Comment: Nice article about configuring in memory database for testing NHibernate: https://ayende.com/blog/3983/nhibernate-unit-testing

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to wrap your ISession in another interface/concrete class so you can stub that out:

```
public interface ISessionWrapper 
{
    IQueryable<T> Query<T>();
}

public class SessionWrapper : ISessionWrapper
{
    private readonly ISession _session;

    public SessionWrapper(ISession session)
    {
        _session = session;
    }

    public IQueryable<T> Query<T>()
    {
        return _session.Query<T>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to mock extension method with NSubstitute, however if you know what extension method is using inside, than you can mock that. Your test will use extension method on mocked object and eventually it will use mocked method. Difficult part is to know what is going on inside.

It worked for me in projects, where I knew all the source code and I could check what's inside.