# "not-null property references a null or transient value" when deleting entity using NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nunit

I'm writing a simple application to learn new technologies. I'm stuck at writing unit test for my application:

```
    [Test]
    public void LessonChangeSubjectShouldNotAffectFormerSubjectPersistence()
    {
        // given
        Lesson ExampleLesson = TestDataFactory.CreateLesson();
        Save(ExampleLesson);
        Refresh(ref ExampleLesson);
        Subject formerSubject = ExampleLesson.Subject;

        // when
        Subject subject = TestDataFactory.CreateSubject();
        _subjectService.Save(subject);
        ExampleLesson.ChangeSubject(subject);
        Update(ExampleLesson);
        _subjectService.Update(formerSubject);
        Refresh(ref ExampleLesson);
        formerSubject = _subjectService.Get(formerSubject.Id);
        subject = _subjectService.Get(subject.Id);

        // then
        ExampleLesson.Subject.Should().Be(subject);
        formerSubject.Should().NotBeNull();
        formerSubject.Lessons.Should().NotContain(ExampleLesson);

        Refresh(ref ExampleLesson);

        _subjectService.Delete(formerSubject);
        Refresh(ref ExampleLesson);
        Delete(ExampleLesson);
    }
```

This scenario includes:

1. Creating lesson with default random subject and save it
2. Create new subject and change lesson subject to new one
3. Check whether old subject still exists

This scenario succeeds, but when it comes to cleaning up test fails on the last line with error

> NHibernate.PropertyValueException : not-null property references a null or transient value Register.Core.Model.Lesson.Subject

Subject field in Lesson class is mapped as follows:

```
References(x => x.Subject)
.Cascade.SaveUpdate()
.Column("SubjectId")
.Fetch.Select()
.ForeignKey("FK_Lessons_Subjects")
.Index("IX_Subject")
.LazyLoad()
.Not.Nullable();
```

And Lessons collection in Subject class is mapped as:

```
HasMany(x => x.Lessons)
.Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
.Cascade.All()
.Fetch.Select()
.ForeignKeyConstraintName("FK_Lessons_Subjects")
.Inverse()
.KeyColumn("SubjectId")
.Not.KeyNullable()
.LazyLoad();
```

When I swap

```
    _subjectService.Delete(formerSubject);
```

with

```
    Refresh(ref ExampleLesson);
    Delete(ExampleLesson);
```

there's no complaint from NHibernate and test passes. I'm curious what's going on and why does the order matter. I also would be very grateful if someone could point me to solution for my problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @RadimKöhler now deletion of `formerSubject` deletes also ExampleLesson which is an incorrect behaviour since we changed subject to another

Comment: @RadimKöhler it gets a new parent before, since test changes lesson subject to new one and saves it. Lesson gets new parent before old one is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably due to the alias problem. There are two copies of the lesson there and one is accessible though the formersubject maybe because the lesson collection was not affected by refresh.

My advice to model it:

**subject should not have a collection of lessons**

You have to unnecessarily refresh it all the time without using it to keep the model valid. It will increase over time to be huge and brings all sorts of problems. You will be inclined to filter/enumerate/sort on it which will be an inmemory operation instead a database call.

**[do not abstract away the ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12913174/671619)**

Make services for actual business logic. DataAccessObjects (DAO) are redundant since ISession of NHibernate is already one. Sqlite inmemory databases for unittests have the advantage of also testing the queries to return the right stuff.

example code

```
class Lesson : Entity
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }

    public void ChangeSubject(Subject subject)
    {
        // do some checks

        Subject = subject;
    }
}

class Subject : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


[Test]
public void LessonChangeSubjectShouldNotAffectFormerSubjectPersistence()
{
    var session = GetInMemorySession();
    // given
    Lesson exampleLesson = new Lesson { Name = "Lesson1", Subject = new Subject { Name = "Subject1" } };
    session.Save(exampleLesson.Subject);    // because we havent set cascade.save
    session.Save(exampleLesson);
    var formerSubjectId = exampleLesson.Subject.Id;

    // when
    Subject subject = new Subject { Name = "Subject2" };
    session.Save(subject);
    exampleLesson.ChangeSubject(subject);
    session.Flush();    // save all changes
    session.Clear();

    var formerSubject = session.Get<Subject>(formerSubjectId);
    subject = session.Get<Subject>(subject.Id);

    // then
    exampleLesson.Subject.Should().Be(subject);
    formerSubject.Should().NotBeNull();

    // technically not needed because the inmemory database is gone after this test
    session.Delete(formerSubject);
    session.Delete(subject);
}
```