# fluent NHibernate not saving the foreign key in HasMany. The column remains null

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am struggling to have the Foreign Keys in my mappings.

My Model looks like this:

```
 public class Accountant: Entity
    {
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Company> Companies { get; set; }

    }

    public class Company: Entity
    {
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual Subscriber Subscriber { get; set; }
        public virtual Accountant Accountant { get; set; }
        public virtual Funder Funder { get; set; }  
    }
```

and my Mappings look like this

```
     public class AccountantMap : ClassMap<Accountant>
    {
        public AccountantMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id);
            Map(x => x.Name);

            HasMany(x => x.Companies)
               .Inverse()
              .Cascade.All();

            Table("tblAccountant");
        }
    }
 public class CompanyMap : ClassMap<Company>
    {
        public CompanyMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id);
            Map(x => x.Name);

            References(x => x.Subscriber).Cascade.SaveUpdate();
            References(x => x.Accountant).Cascade.SaveUpdate();
            References(x => x.Funder).Cascade.SaveUpdate();

            Table("tblCompany");
        }
    }
```

And so, what I am trying to do, am trying to save the Accountant Object and it must update the foreign key in the table tblCompany

here's how my Save method looks like

```
    public void Create_Accountant()
        {

            var repo = new Repository();

            var companies = new List<Company>();

            companies.Add(repo.GetById<Company>(new Guid("02032BD9-2769-4183-9750-AF1F00A5E191")));
            companies.Add(repo.GetById<Company>(new Guid("F86E8B40-73D2-447E-A525-AF1F00A5E191")));

            var accountant = new Accountant
            {
                Name = "Accountant Simba",
Companies= companies
            };

            repo.Save(accountant);

        }

   public void Save<T>(T entity) where T: Entity
        {
            using (var session = _factory.OpenSession())
            {
                using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        session.SaveOrUpdate(entity);
                        session.Flush();
                        transaction.Commit();
                        //return entity.Id;

                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        transaction.Rollback();
                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

After the code has executed, this is what in my Database

[DB Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhLcv.png)

You'd notice that the Account_id column is empty and it should not be empty.

Someone, please help me, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: not answering the question  but consider not using guid 
 https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/266

Comment: Looks like you are missing `accountant.Companies.AddRange(companies);`

Comment: Also https://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton. and https://stackoverflow.com/a/12913174/671619 on the use of repositories.

Comment: @Firo

Companies was assigned to companies.

I am using guids instead of integers.

Is what I am trying to do possible with Fluent Nhibernate?

I want to first save and Accountant and then use the Accountant ID to update the Companies (which is a foreign key)

Spent three days now and not answer.

Answer (score 0):

The references are not set but `Inverse()` tells NHibernate to use the references.
Change the code to this then you can't forget to set it anymore.

```
public class Accountant : Entity
{
    public Accountant()
    {
        Companies = new ParentAwareCollection<Company>(c => c.Accountant = this, c => c.Accountant = null);
    }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Company> Companies { get; protected set; }
}

public sealed class ParentAwareCollection<TChild> : Collection<TChild>
{
    private readonly Action<TChild> _setParent;
    private readonly Action<TChild> _removeParent;

    public ParentAwareCollection(Action<TChild> setParent, Action<TChild> removeParent)
    {
        _setParent = setParent;
        _removeParent = removeParent;
    }

    protected override void InsertItem(int index, TChild item)
    {
        base.InsertItem(index, item);
        _setParent(item);
    }
    protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
    {
        TChild removedItem = this[index];
        _removeParent(removedItem);
        base.RemoveItem(index);
    }

    protected override void ClearItems()
    {
        foreach (var item in this)
        {
            _removeParent(item);
        }
        base.ClearItems();
    }
}
```

and usage

```
    var accountant = new Accountant
    {
        Name = "Accountant Simba",
        Companies = 
        {
            repo.GetById<Company>(new Guid("02032BD9-2769-4183-9750-AF1F00A5E191")),
            repo.GetById<Company>(new Guid("F86E8B40-73D2-447E-A525-AF1F00A5E191"))
        }
    };
```